# Selenium Chromedriver: Failed to create channel

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been using Selenium Chromedriver for the last couple of weeks and suddenly I've got this weird error. I don't know what's changed suddenly.

```
[2560:6100:1025/082057:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(125)] Failed to create channel.
[ERROR] Unhandled exception occured. SessionNotCreatedError: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"9556.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.22.397933 (1cab651507b88dec79b2b2a22d1943c01833cc1b),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

I'm running the chromedriver with Node.js:

```
var selenium = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome"),
        options = new selenium.Options(),
        service = new selenium.ServiceBuilder().build();

    options.addArguments(["--disable-web-security", "-incognito"]);
    var driver = new selenium.Driver(options, service);
    driver.get(fetchSource.url).then(function() {
        browser = driver;
        fetchSource.ready = true;
        console.log("Ready to fetch data.");
    });
```

Updating the chronedriver version didn't help. Any idea how to solve this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out chrome updated itself, and the new version wasn't compatible with chromedriver for some reason. Running an older version of chrome solved the problem. In Node.js you can customize the path for the runnable chrome by changing the options object:

```
options.setChromeBinaryPath('path\to\chrome');
```

Comment: yea you gotta be careful with updating browsers.  If you are using something like AWS nodes, make sure that you have controlled upgrades by disabling system-wide the automatic updates, otherwise this stuff will pop up

Comment: I'm only using my pc for a little project, but thanks anyway. I could save a lot of time if I knew that was the problem